# I want to make arithmetic mean for first half and then for the second half of array

Tags: java

I made the arithmetic mean for whole the sorted array, but now i want to make the arithmetic mean for first sorted half and second sorted half of array.

Ex: My array is: 77, 99, 44, 55, 22, 88, 11, 00, 66, 33.
My code make in first place the sort.

The outcome of program is: 00 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99.

Now i want to make the mean for first half:
00 11 22 33 44 and print it.

Then i want to make the mean for the second half:
55 66 77 88 99 and print it.

```
public class Array {
private double[] a;
private int NrElmts;
public Array(int max)
    { a = new double[max];
        NrElmts = 0;
    }
public void elements(double value)
    { a[NrElmts] = value;
        NrElmts++;
    }
public void print()
    { for(int j=0; j<NrElmts; j++)
        System.out.print(a[j] + " ");
        System.out.println("");
    }
public void selectionSort()
    {
int out, in, min;
for(out=0; out< NrElmts -1; out++)
{ min = out;
for(in=out+1; in< NrElmts; in++)
if(a[in] < a[min] )
min = in;
invertPositions(out, min); }
}
private void invertPositions(int one, int two)
{ double temp = a[one];
a[one] = a[two];
a[two] = temp;
}
public void mean()
{
  int  i;
  double sum = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < NrElmts; i++) {
     sum+=a[i];}
  double medie = sum/NrElmts;
  System.out.format("Mean is: %.1f", mean);
  System.out.println("");
}
}
```

Comment: I suggest changing `mean()` to take two arguments `mean(int start, int end)` and you can get it to give you the mean of the two halves.

Comment: I also suggest you format the code for readability in your IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public void firstHalfMean(){
        int i;
        double sum = 0;
        int numberOFElements = NrElmts/2;
        for (i = 0; i < NrElmts/2; i++) {   // take sum only till half.
            sum += a[i];
        }
        double mean = sum / numberOFElements;   // sum/half the elements
        System.out.format("Mean is: %.1f", mean);
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public void secondHalfMean(){
        int i;
        double sum = 0;
        int numberOFElements = NrElmts % 2 == 0 ? NrElmts/2 : NrElmts/2 + 1; // If odd, this second array will contain one more element.
        for (i = NrElmts/2; i < NrElmts; i++) {   // take sum for the next half
            sum += a[i];
        }
        double mean = sum / numberOFElements;  // sum/half elements  (half + 1) in case of odd length.
        System.out.format("Mean is: %.1f", mean);
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have way to make mean for entire array, all you need to do is find mid position of array and then run from and to that point. 
In your example: NrElmts is 10, so divide your NrElmnts by 2, so you can get mean for 1 to 5, and then 6 to 10 both 5 each.

Think about situation where you have odd number of elements in array, how do u want to do it, whether in first array or second. let me know if this need help as well.

Steps:
1) create a new variable say a1 to NrElmts/2, and go with your mean function from 1 to a1 
2) go from a1+1 to NrElmnts

Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: I do not know what you want to say.

Comment: public void medieAritmetica()
{
      int  i, a1;
      double sum = 0;
      for(a1 = 0; a1 <NrElmts/2;a1++)
          
      for(i = 0; i < NrElmts; i++) {
         sum+=a[i];}
      double medie = sum/NrElmts;
      System.out.format("Media este: %.1f", medie);
      System.out.println("");
}

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the mean for 9, 2 and 7 you have to firstly add them all up, which equals 18 and then divide by how many there are - so 18 / 3 which is 6.
Although, you will have to account for the possibility of an odd list - if there's an odd amount of elements, say for example 1, 2, 3 the middle point of 3 - is 1.5 - and if you're iterating through indexes the iterative variable will count the middle point as 1. So it's a bit tricky, not sure what you'd want to do.
Consider the following code though - it does exactly what you want, but with odd list sizes, it will just divide by a decimal value

```
        LinkedList<Integer> numbers = new LinkedList<>();
        numbers.add(10);
        numbers.add(20);
        numbers.add(30);
        numbers.add(40);        

        int size = numbers.size();

        int iterativeHalf = size / 2;
        float meanHalf = (float) size / 2;

        float lowerMean = 0;
        float upperMean = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            int realRef = i + 1;
            Integer value = numbers.get(i);

            if (realRef > iterativeHalf) { //Should be calculating upper mean
                if (upperMean == 0) { //if lowerMean is just a running total, not divided yet to get the mean
                    System.out.println("the lower mean for numbers is " + lowerMean + " / " + meanHalf);
                    lowerMean = (lowerMean) / meanHalf; //add last value + divide to set it to the mean
                }

                System.out.println("upper mean = " + upperMean + " + " + value + " = " + (upperMean + value));
                upperMean = upperMean + value; //keep the upper values up total going

            } else {
                System.out.println("lower mean = " + lowerMean + " + " + value + " = " + (lowerMean + value));
                lowerMean = lowerMean + value; //keep adding the lower halfs values up
            }
        }
        //When it breaks, must divide upperMean by size to get mean
        System.out.println("the upper mean for numbers is " + upperMean + " / " + meanHalf);
        upperMean = (upperMean) / meanHalf;
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("FINAL lower mean = " + lowerMean);
        System.out.println("FINAL upper mean = " + upperMean);
```

Output is:

```
lower mean = 0.0 + 10 = 10.0
lower mean = 10.0 + 20 = 30.0
the lower mean for numbers is 30.0 / 2.0
upper mean = 0.0 + 30 = 30.0
upper mean = 30.0 + 40 = 70.0
the upper mean for numbers is 70.0 / 2.0

FINAL upper mean = 35.0
FINAL lower mean = 15.0
```

This, for a [10, 20, 30, 40] will yield the output shown above but essentially (10+20)/2 as the lower mean and (30+40)/2 for the upper mean.
For [10, 20, 30, 40, 50] will yield (10 + 20) / 2.5 the lower mean and (30+40+50)/2.5 for the upper mean

Answer (score 0):

Only take sum of half the array. Give one more element to your second or first half in case if your array size is odd.

```java
    public void firstHalfMean(){
        int i;
        double sum = 0;
        int numberOFElements = NrElmts/2;
        for (i = 0; i < NrElmts/2; i++) {   // take sum only till half.
            sum += a[i];
        }
        double mean = sum / numberOFElements;   // sum/half the elements
        System.out.format("Mean is: %.1f", mean);
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public void secondHalfMean(){
        int i;
        double sum = 0;
        int numberOFElements = NrElmts % 2 == 0 ? NrElmts/2 : NrElmts/2 + 1; // If odd, this second array will contain one more element.
        for (i = NrElmts/2; i < NrElmts; i++) {   // take sum for the next half
            sum += a[i];
        }
        double mean = sum / numberOFElements;  // sum/half elements  (half + 1) in case of odd length.
        System.out.format("Mean is: %.1f", mean);
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much.